# Can you get input from devices aside from the keyboard in C's standard library?

Tags: c, input, io, user-input, history

I was reading a book from 1997 that teaches how to program in C, and it always uses the word “usually” when specifying that functions like scanf take input from the keyboard. Because of this, I'm curious as to if functions like scanf can take input from other devices, or if it used to.

Comment: The ```scanf()``` function reads input from the standard input stream ```stdin```, so any device associated with it can be compatible with scanf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Because of this, I'm curious as to if functions like scanf can take input from other devices, or if it used to.

`scanf` takes input from the program's standard input.  What this is connected to is a matter of the operating environment and the way the program is launched.  (Look up "I/O redirection"). It is not unusual for a program's standard input to be connected to a file on disk or to the output of another program.  It sometimes is connected to a socket.  More rarely, it is connected to a serial port, or to a null device, or a source of zeroes or random bytes.

Historically, it might have been connected to a card or paper tape reader.

In principle, it can be connected to *any* device that produces data -- a mouse, for example -- but just because something is possible doesn't make it useful.

Comment: Thanks and this will be very interesting to note.

Comment: I think, @John Bollinger 's answer is correct.
Abstract the input interface internally within the operating system and work on connections with other devices under the corresponding abstraction layer. Keyboard input is the default setting now, but you may be able to connect to another input. But I don't know if that's reasonable.

Linux defines each device as a file and allows all devices to open, read, write, and close through fd.

Answer (score 2):

After `freopen( ..., ...., stdin)`, `scanf()` input can come from many possible sources.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use this for getting input from another source?

Comment: Create file "sometextfile.txt" and then try `freopen("sometextfile.txt", "r", stdin);` to read it via `stdin`.